# Which algebraic identities survive the journey to the powerset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Given an algebraic structure $A$ (call its underlying set $U$) we can obtain a new algebraic structure $B$ with underlying set $V=\mathcal{P}(U)$ in the obvious way. In particular, if $f : U^n \rightarrow U$ is an operation of $A$, then we have a corresponding operation $f' : V^n \rightarrow V$ defined as follows.

$$f'(X_0,\cdots,X_{n-1}) = \{f(x_0,\cdots,x_{n-1}) : x_0 \in X_0, \cdots x_{n-1} \in X_{n-1}\}.$$

I think that in the case where $f$ is a nullary function (i.e. a constant), the above definition reduces to the following.

$$f' = \{f\}.$$

Anyway, since the signature of $A$ is identical to that of $B$, we can ask:

**Question.** Which identities are preserved in the passage from $A$ to $B$?

*Discussion.* It is well known that the associativity and commutativity of any binary operations in the signature will necessarily survive the journey. So I'm thinking that, if every variable occurs precisely once on each side of an identity, then the identity should be preserved. I do not know whether this condition is necessary.

Comment: I think it would make sense to ask about general first order properties preserved by this operation. But it seems rather hard in general.

Comment: @tomasz, that's an interesting point. I'm thinking, at the very least, that all existential statements are probably preserved: e.g if there is a number $x$ with $x^2=1$, then clearly there is a subset $X$ with $X^2=1$, namely $X=\{x\}$.

Comment: Well, first thing is, there is actually a neutral element if the initial operation has one, that is $\{e\}$.

Comment: The neutral element satisfies $e\cdot x=x=x\cdot e$ for all $x$, not $x\cdot e=e$ for all $x$. So $\{e\}$ is a neutral element just fine, and $\emptyset \{e\}=\{e\}\emptyset=\emptyset$, just as it should be.

Comment: @tomasz, ah yes you're right of course. I think that the identities $ex = x$ and $xe = x$ are preserved precisely because $x$ appears once on each side of the identity. On the other hand, the identity $x0=0$ does not survive the journey, presumably because its "unbalanced" in that $x$ occurs only on the left.

Comment: @tomasz, so therefore, $\exists e \forall x(ex=x)$ is preserved.

Comment: You're right in that identities where each variable occurs only once on each side are preserved, this can be calculated directly without much trouble. It seems to me that preserving identities where there are more terms on one side than on the other is going to be, most of the time, rather accidental, simply because the sheer number of combinations on one side will be much larger than that on the other side. Purely existential statements will indeed be preserved, because any expression true for a set of elements will evaluate analogously for their singletons.

Comment: Also, for group operations, the structure will be invariably quite pathological: the entire $A$ will always "swallow" any nonempty set under the derived operation, and the empty set will "vanish" any set under any operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered in Theorem 2 of

Identities for globals (complex algebras) of algebras, Colloquium Mathematicum 56:19-29, 
[Eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/265392),
[ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258112913_Identities_for_globals_complex_algebras_of_algebras).

where it is shown that an identity is preserved when passing to power set algebras iff (i) the same variables appear on both sides, and (ii) the identity can be obtained by identification of variables from an identity where each variable occurs at most once on each side.